# JPA many to one: get elements

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, many-to-many, relationship

I have a problem, that I would like to explain with the following example:

JPA class Person:

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons")
    private List<Car> cars= new ArrayList<>();

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars= cars;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }
```

and where the problem shows itself:

Servlet class:

```
Person person = genericDao.findOne(1);
request.setAttribute("person", person.getName());

List<Car> cars= new ArrayList<Car>();    
cars= person.getCars();
request.setAttribute("cars", cars);
```

The problem is that when trying to get the cars. They aren't automatically retrieved from the database and saved in the array in the Person class. How can I setup a JPA class with a Many to Many relationship, from which I can easily retrieve objects with a relationship.

Car.java

IMPORTS LEFT OUT!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DSD_Cars")
public class Car extends ModifiableEntity {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="DSD_Persons_Cars",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="IDCar", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "IDPerson", referencedColumnName = "ID")}
    )
    private List<Person> persons= new ArrayList<>();

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons= persons;
    }

     public List<Persons> getPersons() {
        return persons;
     }}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Car` Entity?

Comment: Sure, I have edited my original message:)

Comment: What's exactly the problem? `person.getCars()` returns empty list? Are you sure that you really have cars associated with that person in the database?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that. If I manually create a List<Car> with cars, I can use it in the JSP pages. Even iterate through it with a foreach loop. Using the getCars() method the JSP shows either nothing or an error saying the Car object is unknown (no error when creating a manual List<Car>).

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid object name 'Car'. This is the error I get when using the List<Car> from the Person class

Comment: In the future questions, please don't ignore errors as if they're decoration. Tell about them in your question directly. They namely contain the answer to your question. We just have to translate them in  layman's terms for you based on the code provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved:

The Car class had an  @Table(name = "DSD_Cars") annotation. However, the @Table used a wrong import rule. After changing the @Table type to the JPA version, everything worked. It seems JPA uses the class name if the @Table isn't defined properly. That explains the error.

Thanks to everyone who spent time to help me!